How to configure ACL policies in Consul for granular access control of services with the same name?
I am using Consul for service discovery with ACLs enabled. I have registered two instances of the same service but with different IDs:
{
  "ID": "my-service-1",
  "name": "my-service",
  "port": 50001
}

{
  "ID": "my-service-2",
  "name": "my-service",
  "port": 50002
}

I also have a consumer system that queries for the 'my-service' instances using the /v1/catalog/service/:service-name endpoint.
I want to configure ACL policies in Consul to restrict the consumer system so that it only receives information about one of the service instances, even though they share the same service name.
I created a policy which grants read for 'my-service'
service "my-service" {
  policy = "read"
}

node_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}

This works in the intended way. When querying for 'my-service' I receive both service instances 'my-service-1' and 'my-service-2'.
Is there a way to define a policy along the lines of,
service_ID "my-service-1" {
  policy = "read"
}

node_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}

